# Loop cut creates edge that vertices aren't attached to

Tags: modeling, loop

[image]

I created this mesh by applying a boolean modifier to two cubes. I now want to convert the n-gons to quads by creating loop cuts. When I do this by snapping the loop cut to the vertice of the inner cube, it creates weird geometry, where the new edge isn't connected to the vertice.
[image]

I realized I can create what I want by using the Knife tool, but I'm trying to better understand the loop cut tool and wonder how I can fix this issue.

Comment: If you would read my answer to your last question thouroughly you would at least know how to fix this even though it is not connected. And the reason it is not connected is that the _Loop Cut_ tool cuts faces from one edge to the opposite edge - between vertices, not at vertices. The snapping only moves the cut towards the vertex, but it's not making the _Loop Cut_ tool suddenly cutting to vertices instead of edges. What I'm wondering but didn't address yesterday: why you want a horizontal cut specifically instead of doing it like answered below - that is quad topology if this is your goal.

Answer (score 1):

I can see your thinking, but I believe this is intended functionality. The edge loop is seperate from the boolean edge, thus layering them on top of each other will produce broken shading. If your only goal is to go from the ngons to quads I would suggest creating new edges between the boolean'd corners and the original cubes corners like this:
[image: cube]

Additionally, if you really want this edge loop, you can create vertices on the edge loop you created above the boolean'd hole vertices, then join the vertices using M > At Last (assuming you selected the hole vertices after you selected the edge loop vertices) like this:

[image: blender]

Comment: Instead of having to create new vertices on the edge loop, the _Auto Merge_ option can be used too since the edge is already where it should be connected after snapping to the hole vertices, as I answered on his other question regarding this problem yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly, (at least, to me,) if you switch the 'Split Edges and Faces' option on, in *Header* > *Automerge*, new vertices get cut in to the fresh loop, if <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> is snapped:

[image]

But IMO, it would be preferable always to look for a way without Booleans, if you can.

In this case, possibly, using a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> bevel on crossed loops, an inset, and an extrusion:

[image]